# Varchar column can only be filtered with LIKE rather than = in select statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two columns, id (integer) and code (characters varying 50).

This is how my table looks like:

```
id       code
9135     2NLX
```

when I do a select statement like this

```
select * from table where code = '2NLX'
```

it shows nothing.

When I do it like this however, the row shows up:

```
select * from table where code like '%2NLX%'
```

Why is this happening? It doesn't look like there is a leading space or spaces in the code field. When I paste the data in excel there are no random spaces. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You can easily test for leading or trailing whitespace using `where trim(code) = '2NLX'`

Comment: What do you see if you do `select code, length(code) from table where code like '%2NLX%'`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name damn that query worked. Is there a way to mass update the table to get rid of all leading and trailing whitespace?

Comment: `update table set code = trim(code)`...